# Audit user activity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Please advice how can I audit all actions of specific user in SQL Server 2008 EE? If it can be traced and written to log file? If the audit has the levels?

With regards!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/30/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to see all activity from a single user.

The quickest would be a profiler trace filtered to that user, start a trace and in the Event Selection and Column Filters add the user under "Like" in the LoginName filter, or NTUserName if appropriate.

[image: Example]

Beware of overhead when using profiler in production it can be resource hungry.

If you want something more long term, you can look into auditing. Here is a useful tutorial for Select Statements but there is much more you can do with it.

[Auditing Select Statements 2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sreekarm/2009/01/05/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008/)

Answer (score -2):

As sqlblog of jonathan_kehayias [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/) you can trace like who and from what machine a server side trace was created.

First execute the this TSQL query.

```
select 
    trace_event_id, 
    name
from sys.trace_events
where name like '%trace%';
Go
```

You shall get the output like here 
[image]

The run the next TSQL query like

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(MAX)  

SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) + '\Log.trc'  
FROM sys.traces   
WHERE is_default = 1;  

SELECT 
    LoginName, 
    HostName, 
    ApplicationName, 
    StartTime, 
    TextData
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable( @FileName, DEFAULT ) AS gt  
WHERE EventClass = 175;
Go
```

This information is tracked in the Default Trace and can be found by querying for `EventClass 175` which is the Audit Server Alter Trace Event trace_event_id from sys.trace_events.
[image]